After installing I could not fine it on my windows computer I placed it on D drive but I can’t see it I was unable to run it Tryed to reinstel its the
When I try to run Ubuntu it tells me it's not there. But there is something on my D drive. Ubuntu 22.04 seems to be hidden on it. I don't know how to state it. I think I'll format the drive again and try again. Note my D drive was empty, when I started. I was going for a dual boot system. Can you help me start over?

If you installed on an entirely different drive then the installer might have installed the Grub boot loader on that drive. If so, use your firmware to choose that drive to boot from.

Windows does not recognize partition formats used by Ubuntu. That may be why it looks empty. Boot from Ubuntu live USB. Use the Try option. Use the app gparted. Take a screenshot. Add it to your question.

Does this answer your question? Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot
